# String splitting issue problem with multiword expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of strings like:

```
'i would like a blood orange'
```

I also have a list of strings like:

```
["blood orange", "loan shark"]
```

Operating on the string, I want the following list:

```
["i", "would", "like", "a", "blood orange"]
```

What is the best way to get the above list? I've been using re throughout my code, but I'm stumped with this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward generator implementation: split the string into words, group together words which form phrases, and yield the results.

(There may be a cleaner way to handle `skip`, but for some reason I'm drawing a blank.)

```
def split_with_phrases(sentence, phrase_list):
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    phrases = set(tuple(s.split(" ")) for s in phrase_list)
    print phrases
    max_phrase_length = max(len(p) for p in phrases)

    # Find a phrase within words starting at the specified index.  Return the
    # phrase as a tuple, or None if no phrase starts at that index.
    def find_phrase(start_idx):
        # Iterate backwards, so we'll always find longer phrases before shorter ones.
        # Otherwise, if we have a phrase set like "hello world" and "hello world two",
        # we'll never match the longer phrase because we'll always match the shorter
        # one first.
        for phrase_length in xrange(max_phrase_length, 0, -1):
            test_word = tuple(words[idx:idx+phrase_length])
            if test_word in phrases:
                return test_word
        return None

    skip = 0
    for idx in xrange(len(words)):
        if skip:
            # This word was returned as part of a previous phrase; skip it.
            skip -= 1
            continue

        phrase = find_phrase(idx)
        if phrase is not None:
            skip = len(phrase)
            yield " ".join(phrase)
            continue

        yield words[idx]

print [s for s in split_with_phrases('i would like a blood orange',
    ["blood orange", "loan shark"])]
```

Comment: You are correct.  Your solution is definitely better than either of the ones that I hastily provided.  I'm not sure whether it is more appropriate to correct mine or just point this out.

Comment: @blackkettle, I think you could correct yours, but if it would look exactly like this one, there would be no point, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is crazy, crude and ugly. But looks like it works. You may wanna clean and optimize it but certain ideas here might work.

```
list_to_split = ['i would like a blood orange', 'i would like a blood orange ttt blood orange']
input_list = ["blood orange", "loan shark"]

for item in input_list:
    for str_lst in list_to_split:
        if item in str_lst:
            tmp = str_lst.split(item)
            lst = []
            for itm in tmp:
                if itm!= '':
                    lst.append(itm)
                    lst.append(item)
            print lst
```

output:

```
['i would like a ', 'blood orange']
['i would like a ', 'blood orange', ' ttt ', 'blood orange']
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty, completely un-optimized approach might be to just replace the compounds in the string with a version including a different separator (preferably one that does not occur anywhere else in your target string or compound words).  Then split and replace.  A more efficient approach would be to iterate only once through the string, matching the compound words where appropriate - but you may have to watch out for instances where there are nested compounds, etc., depending on your array.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

my_string = "i would like a blood orange"
compounds = ["blood orange", "loan shark"]
for i in range(0,len(compounds)):
    my_string = my_string.replace(compounds[i],compounds[i].replace(" ","&"))

my_segs = re.split(r"\s+",my_string)    
for i in range(0,len(my_segs)):
    my_segs[i] = my_segs[i].replace("&"," ")
print my_segs
```

Edit: Glenn Maynard's solution is better.

Comment: This fails with the input `"xxxblood orangexxx"`; it needs to match whole words.  More generally speaking, this approach is okay as long as you know what your input looks like; for the general case you need to watch out for your placeholder character being present in the string (`"i drink blood&orange juice"`), which means escaping.

Comment: @Glenn I think I covered these issues in my initial description.  Based on the OP description I would also think that "xxxblood orangexxx" and "blood orange" should be treated as completely different strings.

Comment: It's always nice when people accept the first answer they see, without bothering to read anything.

Comment: That was my point: they should almost certainly be treated as different strings.  This answer doesn't do that, and returns `"xxxblood orangexxx"` as a phrase.  (The OP didn't specify--I doubt he thought it through that far, and will probably be bitten by bugs later on as a result.)  Anyhow, the OP obviously isn't paying attention, so I'm moving on.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: @alphomega:  Yeah. I did provide an answer that works very early, even if my variables names were ugly and is not efficient with lists